# Casting to a generic list of variables of dynamic type

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, types, casting

I need to change the `Capacity` property of the dynamic variable of type `List<*DynamicType*>`.
The problem is that `Activator` returns `object`-casted variable if variable type is not specified instead of proper `List<*DynamicType*>` and the best I can do is to cast it to `IList`:

```
DynamicTypeBuilder builder = new DynamicTypeBuilder() { ... };
Type dataType = builder.GenerateType(...);
Type listDataType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(dataType);
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listDataType);
```

After some searching I found only one hack:

```
dynamic dynamicList = list;
dynamicList.Capacity = dataRowsCount;
```

Though this would be acceptable in my case I wonder if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is simpler:

```
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listDataType,
    new object[]{dataRowsCount});
```

Which should use the correct constructor?

Generics and reflection are indeed a pain in combination. The `dynamic` hack here is no uglier than setting it via reflection (a magic string as a literal, vs an unverified property member), and `dynamic` is internally optimised and cached (per-type), so I wouldn't have a problem with it. If you need to do more than just one property, you can also use `dynamic` to flip into a generic method, to minimise the ugly:

```
void Evil<T>(List<T> list, int capacity) {
    list.Capacity = capacity;
    // do other stuff
}
...
dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(listDataType);
Evil(list, dataRowsCount);
```

Which will invoke the generic method with the correct `T`. Not worth it just for 1 member, but it might be useful for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Forgot about that constructor. As I need to set only that property, doing it this way is really simpler. And I also like your suggestion to use generic method to "cast" the IList object, very nice.

Comment: BTW, though I may be doing something wrong, but assigning the result of `Activator.CreateInstance()` to `generic` variable in my case won't work, because `list.Add(*Dynamically created dataType object*)` results in exception, and with pre-casting `list` to `IList` it works.

Comment: @Dmitry sure, then cast to `IList`. I didn't do that in the example, simply because I was illustrating the minimum to perform the operations *in the example*, and the example has no `Add(...)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with reflection:

```
var capacityProperty = listDataType.GetProperty("Capacity");
capacityProperty.SetValue(list, dataRowsCount, null);
```

An alternative is to write a generic method which does everything you want in a statically typed way, and call *that* with reflection instead. That can be a handy way of making sure you only need one piece of reflection.

Comment: Nice, haven't thought about reflection for some reason. I'll have this in mind when I deal with dynamic\generics again.